# Formatting numbers in excel so they are in parentheses

Tags: microsoft-excel, format

I want to format cells in Excel so the numbers the cells contain are displayed in parentheses (both negative and positive numbers). Examples:

(4.54)

(-2.32)

The cells I want to format this way contain formulas. This seems to be the reason why custom formatting doesn't work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want a custom number format:

```
"("0.00")";"("-0.00")"
```

This defines the format for positives `"("0.00")"` and another for negatives `"("-0.00")"`

You could optionally provide a third format for zero value but if you don't specify it then zero will be formatted using the positive format.

Comment: This works great. Now just find out the version of excel that the OP is using and gives steps on how to do this.

Comment: This works perfectly for when cells contain values, but doesn't seem to work when they contain formulas. Any idea how to deal with that?

Comment: @FBert - this should work the same for both constants and formulas? Do your formulas results numbers formatted as text? Please update your question with some sample formula you us.

Comment: Right - my formulas reference to another sheet. that sheet however contains numbers in the following way: ="4.44". I guess the "" are causing the problem

Comment: @FBert, yes, `="4.44"` is a text value, not a numeric value so the custom number format as specified will not be applied. If you want to place parentheses around text values as well then you can supply a full custom format for positives, negatives, zero and text, which would be `"("0.0")";"("-0.0")";"("-0.0");"("@")"` but I recommend you to use genuine numeric values wherever possible and your overall Excel experience will be much more productive.

Answer (score 0):

Add a single quote before you type the value into the cell

```
'(4.54)
'(-2.32)
```

Then press enter and the single quote will be removed and the literal value you typed in will remain

Comment: i just tried this in Excel 2010. It doesn't work.

Comment: @jo99blackops What output do you get?  I've been using this for years in all versions of excel and it's worked.  I am currently on 2016 however.

Comment: The answer works but is not very useful because the numbers are converted to text and can no longer be used for calculations.

Comment: I type:   '5.6     and I get this: http://s21.postimg.org/w94rfcqnr/temp.png

Comment: @jo99blackops, OP was suggesting to type `'(5.6)` including the parentheses. It works under all versions of Excel but converts the result to a string of text, no longer a numeric value.

Comment: @MikeFitzpatrick OP also didn't mention that they needed the number for calculations, that is why I assumed string of text would be suitable

Comment: @tyelford Sorry, I misunderstood you. It does work.

Comment: @tyelford -could you edit or delete your answer, as it is incorrect, the original question asks to format the cells to have brackets even if they are positive or negative numbers.